# Rails Issue with Time.now in view vs controller

Tags: ruby, time, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to do a `Time.now` in my controller when I set one of the variables. What is occuring is when I display it I am getting a value of `2000-01-01 10:44:11 -0500`. When I do `<%= Time.now %>` in my view I get the correct time `2014-03-05 11:39:17 -0500`.

Is there a reason for this?

Here is my controller code

```
def create_checkout_values
    @checked_out = CheckedOut.new
    @checked_out.bike_id=checked_out_params[:bike_id]
    @checked_out.user=User.find_by_login(checked_out_params[:user_id])
    @checked_out.time_of_checkout=Time.now

    @bike = Bike.find_by_bike_id(@checked_out.bike_id)
    if @bike != nil
      @checked_out.problem = @bike.problem_description
      @checked_out.fixed = @bike.need_repair
    else
      @checked_out.problem = ""
      @checked_out.fixed = false
    end
  end
```

Comment: hard to say without your controller code

Comment: @JohnNaegle that is the method in my controller that is called

Comment: use the `l` (`localize`) helper to output date/times

Comment: @MarianTheisen Where should I be usling `l`?

Comment: Is the data type of time_of_checkout actually time? One more tiny thing, add spaces before and after using = in line_number 4 and 5. P.s. You can also use Time.now.localtime.

Comment: @rails4guides.com in my schema file you can see `t.time     "time_of_checkout"`. I tried adding localtime at the end and that is not doing anything differently.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the type of the time_of_checkout column to datetime instead of just time.
From your code it seems you really want to store a date + time there, not just the time part of Time.now (which returns the full date and time, not just the time). When you save the record AR converts (means here: eats the date) the full datetime to time only, that is why you see the date with the year 2000